# Get context id corresponding to the current period

Tags: xml-parsing, xbrl

I'm trying to parse a list of xbrl instance files. The filings (10-Q) correspond to different companies from different industries, reporting under us-gaap.

I'm trying to extract the values of Revenue for the current 3-month period. In order to do that I'm trying to get the value of "us-gaap:Revenues" element.

The problem is that there're many "us-gaap:Revenues" elements corresponding to different contexts. How do I let the parser know which context corresponds to the current period and is for the whole company (not for the segments)?

Comment: if you tell us which parser/language you are using, the code you already have, and maybe also a minimal xbri example, you might get help faster, especially from people that know XML parsing, but not the xbri standard.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the phrase "let the parser know"? Which parser are you using? What environment are you using? .NET? Java? Python?

Comment: I'm using R and the package XML. I'm working with the instance files only since I'm not sure how to work with other files in the XBRL report. What I do is I get the value of the nodes which correspond to revenues. For example, <us-gaap:Revenues contextRef="c20140901to20150228" unitRef="U002" decimals="-6">46127000000</us-gaap:Revenues>.

Comment: Actually, I can use the context from the EntityregistrationName node. The problem is that for some reason XBRL creators decided to make  the context reference to the period from previous fiscal year end date to current quarter end date instead of from the previous quarter end date to the current quarter end date: <dei:EntityRegistrantName contextRef="c20140901to20150228">Walgreens Boots Alliance, Inc.</dei:EntityRegistrantName>

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about your work, I believe you need some basic XBRL processor to help working with XBRL easier. There are many open-source and proprietary processors.

Coming back to your question, I think the ideal way would be to fetch all the contexts matching the period you are looking for. Then querying for the us-gaap:Revenue facts for each of those contexts.

On your question "How do I let the parser know which context is for the whole company (not for the segments)?" - I believe there is a dimension (or axis) that you are looking for. Usually the dimension member corresponding to the whole company is the default one (confirm this by looking at the taxonomy). And since contexts usually omit the default dimension values, you have to look for the contexts that don't have that dimension in their segment (or scenario).

You can browse the us-gaap taxonomy in the online Taxonomy Viewer tool provided by FASB.

One thing to make sure is, there can be Revenue facts in the extension taxonomy as well and you might be interested in those as well. This is a big issue with US-GAAP taxonomy, even though allowing extensions adds flexibility, it degrades the data quality of the filings.